# How do I add a printer in OpenSUSE which is being shared by a CUPS print server?

Tags: cups, printing

I have a print server running CUPS with a printer attached via USB cable.

I want to add this printer to my OpenSUSE tumbleweed desktop. I can't see how to do this. Network discovery in OpenSUSE does not discover the printer.

This was easy to add from a Windows 10 machine and is working fine. Not sure why I can't find the printer from OpenSUSE.

Comment: This might be a firewall issue on your OpenSUSE. Does it work when you specifically enter the server's IP address in the printer discovery?